# Call multiple functions with onClick event in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The only problem I am facing is, either one of them dont work when put together. Both work fine independently. When put together, I can see the routes changing but the active `Item` doesn't switch.

```
 {SidebarData.map((item, index)=>{
      return(
        <div className={selected===index?'menuItem active': 'menuItem'}
        key={index}
        onClick={()=>{setSelected(index); window.location.pathname= item.link;    }}
       
        >
          <item.icon/>
          <span>
            {item.heading}
          </span>
        </div>
      )
    })}


export const SidebarData = [
  {
    icon: UilEstate,
    heading: "Dashboard",
    link: "/Dashboard",
  },
  {
    icon: UilLaptop ,
    heading: "Exams",
    link: "/Exams",
  },
  {
    icon: UilFileCheck ,
    heading: "Results",
    link: "/Result",
  },
```

Comment: Div elements are not designed to be interactive. Screen readers won't announce them as clickable. Non-pointing device users can't tab to them. Search engines may not find them. Use a link instead.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning a new value to `window.location.pathname` will cause the browser to navigate to the new URL and load it as a new page.

If that URL also serves up your React application, then it will be run from scratch and all existing state (including the result of running `setSelected(index);`)  will be lost.

Use [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction) or [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/routing/creating-routes/) to handle routing with static page generation or server-side rendering. Use [BrowserRouter](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/routers/browser-router) for routing with your own fallback code or [HashRouter](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/routers/hash-router) for a pure single page application with no server-side fallback.

These all have methods for passing state data through the link, so you can avoid using `setState` as well.

(You could also use BrowserRouter and serve up the same content-less bootstrap HTML document for every URL, but that isn't an efficient approach).